# How to check empty in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract, erc20, ether

In solidity can we check if(empty) just like we do in php

Or anything equivalent to that. What I want to do is to check if msg.sender trigger the call with empty msg.value or has put some amount to trigger the function

```
 if (empty(msg.value))
```

Answer (score 1):

`msg.value` is a number(uint) is Solidity so it will be `>=0`, it cannot be empty.